# Infimum and Supremum basic question

Tags: calculus

1) Find supremum and infimum of the subset:

$$\{\cos x:0 \leq x< \pi\}$$

Is this just $\sup=1$ and $\inf=0$? Or is that wrong maybe because $x < \pi$ and not $x\leq\pi$?

2) Let $S$ be a non-empty finite subset of real numbers and let

$$T=\{-x : x \in S\}$$

Show that $\sup(S)=-\inf(T)$ (show first that $-\inf(T)$ is an upper bound for $S$ and that $-\sup(S)$ is a lower bound for $T$).

To show $-\inf(T)$ is an upper bound, do I just find $\inf(T)$ and multiply with $-1$ since the function is $-x$ on all reals, and the same thing to show that $-\sup(S)$ is a lower bound?

ty for tips/solutions!

Comment: What is $\lim_{x \to \pi}\cos(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1)$ $\inf \{\cos x : 0 \leq x \leq \pi\} = -1$

$2)$ If $S$ is finite subset of real numbers you can find the largest one $s$ (by sorting them) so $\sup S = s$. Of course then $-s \in T$ and $-s \geq p$ for every $p \in T$. So $\inf T = -s$.